# Liquibase includeAll tag is ignored

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

Here we go..

We have a **Spring Boot 1.4.0** application and we're using **Liquibase 3.5.1** for our DB management.

All of our individual changeset files are located in `/src/main/resources/db/changelog` and they have the following naming schema: `[semanticVersion]-[descriptor].yml`

The master changelog, however, is located inside a runtime dependency.

```
db.changelog-master.yaml

databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1.0.1
      author: atlassian
      changes:
        - createTable:
            //code omitted for brevity
  - includeAll:
      path: classpath*:db/changelog
      errorIfMissingOrEmpty: false
```

Now to the problem.

Running the application through IDEA all of the changesets are loaded and applied to our DB.

However when I use the Spring Boot Gradle plugin to build a fat jar (`bootRepackage` task) and then proceed to run it with `java -jar [project].jar` the master changelog is found, the table is created but all the other files are seemingly.. ignored. `databasechangelog` table only shows the **1.0.1** update and that's it. Fun fact, if I set the `error` property to `true` it only fails once I also fudge the `path` to something unresolvable. So it seems like the directory is found just fine.

NB! All the `.yml` files are inside the fat jar, checked and double-checked :)

I have also tried renaming them to `.yaml`, I've tried replacing them with corresponding `.xml` files, nothing is resolved.

I dug around on Google, Stack and Liquibase JIRA and found out only a handful of mentions of this happening and from what I read, on **3.5.1** this problem should've been fixed.. but no dice.

If I switch the Liquibase dependency back to **3.4.2** (which was mentioned as a possible solution) and run the jar I get a few thousand lines of exceptions that culminate with an `Exception` saying that `db.changelog-master.yaml` is not recognized as a proper file and `DatabaseChangeLog` node cannot be found.

If I missed any important information just let me know, I tried to be as verbose as possible.

Comment: seems as if spring-boot 1.4.0 does not work with liquibase - see https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2863

Comment: Even if the issue is closed, I still have the same problem with liquibase 3.5.2, 3.5.3 ( includeAll:db/changelog/sql in a jar file)  when launching integration tests with maven. No problem when launching integrations tests from IDE. I must to downgrade to 3.4.1 or move to use `include` instead of `includeAll`

Comment: Maybe this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/41678616/4864870. There are some technical details which could help liquibase developers to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be fixed in a later version of liquibase than what is currently set by spring boot.

Override the version via:

```
ext["liquibase.version"] = "3.5.4"
```

Also, know that this issue still exists in **spring boot 1.5**

Ref: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2863