# liquibase 3.5.X can't find any files for includeAll with relative path

Tags: java, database, liquibase

We are using liquibase 3.4.2 and want to update to 3.5.3 but all my attempts failed because liquibase doesn't find any file which are included by using `includeAll`. I have tested liquibase 3.5.0, 3.5.1 and 3.5.3 (I skipped 3.5.2 because of [this blog post](http://www.liquibase.org/2016/09/liquibase-3-5-2-pulled.html)).

My ChangeSet looks like this:

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

    <includeAll path="relative/dir1" relativeToChangelogFile="true" errorIfMissingOrEmpty="true"/>
    <includeAll path="relative/dir2" relativeToChangelogFile="true" errorIfMissingOrEmpty="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

My directory structure (inside a jar which is included in a war) looks like this:

- `/some/dir/changeset.xml` *(the code above)*
- `/some/dir/relative/dir1/another-changeset.xml`
- `/some/dir/relative/dir2/another-changeset-1.xml`
- `/some/dir/relative/dir2/another-changeset-2.xml`

I have already debugged through liquibase and got stuck at [`ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java:108`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/resource/ClassLoaderResourceAccessor.java#L108):

```
if (entry.getName().startsWith(path)) {
```

In my case `entry.getName()` returns `some` in the first loop, then `some/dir` and so on till `some/dir/relative/dir1/another-changeset-1.xml`, `some/dir/relative/dir2/another-changeset-1.xml` and `some/dir/relative/dir2/another-changeset-2.xml`. But the condition is always false because `path` contains something like `jar:file:/C:/path/to/maven/project/war/target/example.war-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/changesets-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/relative/dir1/` or `jar:file:/C:/path/to/maven/project/war/target/example.war-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/changesets-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/relative/dir2/`

Is this really a bug in liquibase since 3.5.0? It works perfectly if I downgrade to liquibase 3.4.2. It works also if I use `include` instead of `includeAll` but in my real application I have much more changesets and I don't want to list them all manually.

I have found some information on this, but none of them helps me. For the sake of completeness:

- Liquibase-JIRA: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2851, https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2863, https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2898, https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2974
- SO: [Liquibase includeAll tag is ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39334254/4864870), [includeAll path="" not working in 3.5.3, using java -jar method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41460841/4864870)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It does not work with Maven build. I keep getting an exception Caused by: liquibase.exception.SetupException: Could not find directory or directory was empty for includeAll 'dml/services/'

Comment: I also hit an issue like CORE-2851 and related. I submitted a PR that fixed my issue: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/709

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

`<includeAll
    path="file:/absolute/path/to/changeset/folder"
    relativeToChangelogFile="false" />`

Start the path with file:/ and use an absolute path. This is not ideal, but I was able to get liquibase-maven-plugin 3.6.3 to load the changeset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm no longer working on a project which uses liquibase. So I'm not be able to verify you answer.

Comment: I could verify the answer, I spent hours and none of the examples of the works, were quite blurry, this was just water on the desert to me, please give this guy the correct answer. Tested in Liqubase 3.10.0

Comment: Still, it doesn't solve the problem of running Liquibase from a Java application launched with `java -jar ...`.

Comment: To @MaDa point, how does one use this setting where the changeset is in a jar?

Comment: @avanderw At the time I tried relative paths with Maven and was not able to get it working. Given that many others have had similar trouble with relative paths, I assumed that the feature is broken. Instead, I offered an alternative solution that worked for me: use an absolute path, and store the changeset external to the project build (jar, war, etc).